# Odor in old farm house

Tags: chimney

Recently purchased a 80 yr old two story farm house. There are two chimneys in the middle of the house with holes for stove pipes on both floors. There is an odor I can't seem to get out of the house, I have smelled this odor before around sealed off fireplaces, could this odor be comming from these chimneys and would having the chimneys cleaned and capped eliminate the odor? I have noticed there are no caps on the chimneys at the top. These chimneys are no longer in use. There is nothing burning. The chimneys go to the ground and to the roof. I don't have pictures because the house is two story and I can't get on the roof. The chimneys are cinder block.'m trying to find out if the odor could be coming from the build up of creosote in the chimneys.Is this possible?

Comment: Please post pictures of the top of chimney and tbe intersection with the floor. What is the floor and or ceiling material?  In the best case,  it could be the burning of dust.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.